# How to make dataframe table from json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have json file I want to convert it to pandas dataframe, take some variables from 'tags' and take some variables from 'fields'

```
{
    "tags": {
        "ID": "99909",
        "type": "fff",
        "ID2": "565789"
    },
    "timestamp": 1500079519064,
    "tenant": "dxy",
    "tstable": "data",
    "user": "writer",
    "fields": {
        "a": "0.003",
        "b": "0.011",

    }
}
```

Required output:

```
df_out=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[99909],'type':["fff"],'ID2':[565789],"timestamp": [1500079519064],"tenant": ["dxy"],"tstable": ["data"],"user": ["writer"],"a": ["0.003"],"b": ["0.011"]})

print(df_out)
ID type     ID2      timestamp tenant tstable    user      a      b
0  99909  fff  565789  1577078519064    dxy    data  writer  0.003  0.011
```

Comment: This link could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858611/convert-nested-json-to-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json.json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
j = {
    "tags": {
        "ID": "99909",
        "type": "fff",
        "ID2": "565789"
    },
    "timestamp": 1500079519064,
    "tenant": "dxy",
    "tstable": "data",
    "user": "writer",
    "fields": {
        "a": "0.003",
        "b": "0.011",

    }
}

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(j)
print (df)
       timestamp tenant tstable    user tags.ID tags.type tags.ID2 fields.a  \
0  1500079519064    dxy    data  writer   99909       fff   565789    0.003   

  fields.b  
0    0.011
```

Last if necessary change columns names add `rename`:

```
f = lambda x: x.split('.')[-1]
df = json_normalize(j).rename(columns=f)
print (df)
       timestamp tenant tstable    user     ID type     ID2      a      b
0  1500079519064    dxy    data  writer  99909  fff  565789  0.003  0.011
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have nested columns then you first need to normalize the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data = [
  {
    "tags": {
        "ID": "99909",
        "type": "fff",
        "ID2": "565789"
    },
    "timestamp": 1500079519064,
    "tenant": "dxy",
    "tstable": "data",
    "user": "writer",
    "fields": {
        "a": "0.003",
        "b": "0.011",

    }
}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data), orient='columns')

print(df)
```